# http Authentication required for accessing http://localhost:8080

Tags: authentication, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I am trying to use hortonworks sandbox.
the login page of ambari is on link http://localhost:8080.
when i try to access this from my browser it asks for username and password.
It dosent accept my credentials and  autentication failes. I am never directed on login page of ambari. 
[asking for credentials while accessing localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVLmM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Default Username & Password is :raj_ops

You can check it at
http://localhost:1080/splash2.html